# Prove Riemann-Roch for curves from properties of Hilbert polynomial

Tags: algebraic-geometry

The theorem of Riemann-Roch (RR) tell us that
$$ \chi(\mathcal{O}_X(D))=\deg(D)+1-g $$
where $\chi$ is the Euler characteristic of the sheaves, $X$ is a projective non singular curve of genus $g$. From that, we deduce for all integer $n$,
$$ \chi(\mathcal{O}_X(nD))=\deg(D)n+1-g $$
that is, with $H$ the Hilbert polynomial,
$$ H_{\mathcal{O}_X(D)}(t)=\deg(D)t+1-g $$
So I tell me that perhaps one could prove (RR) from properties of the Hilbert polynomial. For example if $\mathrm{Pic}(X)=\mathbb{Z}$, one has $D\sim nH$ with $H$ hyperplan section of $X$ and

$$ \chi (\mathcal{O}_X(D)) =\chi(\mathcal{O}_X(nH))=\chi(\mathcal{O}_X(n))=H_{\mathcal{O}_X}(n) $$

but from general properties of Hilbert polynomial one know that
$$ H_{\mathcal{O}_X}(t)=\deg(X)t+1-g $$

So to prove RR here I only have to check that $\deg(H)=\deg(X)$.

I hope there is no big mistake here, and if is not the case, does someone see why $\deg(H)=\deg(X)$?

Second but maybe more difficult question: can we genereralize this approach for when $\mathrm{Pic}(X)\neq\mathbb{Z}$.

Comment: What is your definition of degree? For a lot of people, it *is* the leading coefficient of the Hilbert polynomial. For me, it's the cardinality of a general hyperplane section, from which the result would also seem to be immediate.

Comment: For me it is the leading coefficient, so your remark about cardinality of general hyperplane section solve my first problem. Thanks!

Comment: Awesome! As for the second question, have you looked in Hartshorne IV.1? As I recall, he just writes down one or two exact sequences and is basically done, which sounds like it's in line with what you want. But I don't know if you're comfortable with sheaf cohomology in general...

Comment: Yes it is my Bible, but it doesn't seem to me that it is the same approach: it is a recurrence over the cardinality of the support of the divisor $D$.